web scraping table using pandas
I am learning web scraping on a course on coursera. I tried the code given in the course on my Mac (I use PyCharm by the way) but I got many errors. I guess it has to do with missing libraries or something like that on my computer because the code given should be true since it is on coursera perhaps.
URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_banks'
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html(URL)
df = tables[0]
print(df)


and here is the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 1344, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1336, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1382, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1331, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1091, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1035, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1477, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 455, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1042, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1320, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anaszahra/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.venv/test1.py", line 3, in <module>
    tables = pd.read_html(URL)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anaszahra/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 1240, in read_html
    return _parse(
           ^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anaszahra/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 983, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anaszahra/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 249, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anaszahra/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 806, in _build_doc
    raise e
  File "/Users/anaszahra/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 785, in _build_doc
    with get_handle(
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anaszahra/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 728, in get_handle
    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anaszahra/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 384, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    with urlopen(req_info) as req:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anaszahra/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 289, in urlopen
    return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 215, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 515, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 532, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 492, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 1392, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 1347, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)>


I ran it multiple times, tried to look for missing libraries or anything like that

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask something specific. Also take the [tour].

Install or update certifi, and also pip upgrade your installed python packages. Your code works.

thanks Barry. I did as you said and made sure that my packages are upgraded, but unfortunately I still get the same error

Maybe this question will help you. Especially this response: bash /Applications/Python*/Install\ Certificates.command. Try it and let us know how you got on.
